# asynchronous express app setup unit testing using EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, events, asynchronous

I'm trying to unit test the setup code of an express app. Some of the setup is asynchronous (async_function) and so I've added a way for the app to get notified when the async setup is complete, using either a 'setup-complete' or 'setup-failure' event.

The unit test does the setup in the nodeunit setUp function and the callback to tell nodeunit that the setup is complete is executed fine for test1, but test2 fails. For some reason I get different errors depending on where I run the test.

Run in Webstorm - nodeunit async module error:
iterator(x.value, function (err, v) {
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Run on cmd line:
$ ../node_modules/nodeunit/bin/nodeunit --reporter verbose test.js
test.js
✔ asynchronous express app setup - test1
  ✔ async_function produced a result
  ✔ result has value specified in the test

FAILURES: Undone tests (or their setups/teardowns):
 
- asynchronous express app setup - test2

To fix this, make sure all tests call test.done()

As far as I can tell I've ran t.done() in the right places. 
It's probably an obvious mistake that I've missed, I've been looking at this code for a long time.

Can someone advice and or help?

app.js:

```
var
  async_function     = require( './lib/async_function' ),
  express            = require( 'express' ),
  path               = require( 'path' ),
  app                = express(),
  options            = require( './lib/options' ),
  setupErrorHandlers = require( './lib/error_handlers' );

// do some app setup stuff
app.set( 'views', path.join( __dirname, 'views' ) );
app.set( 'view engine', 'ejs' );
app.disable( "x-powered-by" );

app = async_function( app, options, function ( err ) {
  if ( err ) return app.async_function.setupFailed( err );
  setupErrorHandlers( app );
  app.async_function.setupComplete();
});

module.exports = app;
```

async_function.js:

```
var
  events = require( 'events' ),
  setup  = new events.EventEmitter;

var addSetupEventToApp = function ( app ) {
  var fn = {};
  fn.__proto__.then = function ( onSetupComplete, onFailedSetup ) {
    setup.on( 'setup-complete', function () { onSetupComplete(); });
    setup.on( 'setup-failed', function ( error ) { onFailedSetup( error ); });
  };
  fn.__proto__.setupComplete = function ( value ) {
    setup.emit( 'setup-complete', value );
  };
  fn.__proto__.setupFailed = function ( error ) {
    setup.emit( 'setup-failed', error );
  };
  app.async_function = fn;
};

module.exports = function ( app, options, cb ) {
  addSetupEventToApp( app );
  setTimeout( function () {
    if ( app.result ) throw new Error( "AlreadyConfiguredAppError" );
    app.result = options.arg1 + options.arg2;
    cb();
  }, 5000 );
  return app;
};
```

test.js:

```
var
  nodeunit   = require( 'nodeunit' ),
  proxyquire = require( 'proxyquire' );

var continueTesting = function() {
  callback();
};
var stopTesting = function( err ) {
  callback( err );
};

exports[ 'asynchronous express app setup' ] = nodeunit.testCase({
  setUp: function ( callback ) {
    proxyquire.noPreserveCache();
    this.app = proxyquire( '../app', {
      './lib/options': {
        arg1: "zxcvbnm",
        arg2: "1234567890"
      }
    });
    this.app.then( continueTesting, stopTesting );
  },

  tearDown: function ( callback ) {
    delete this.app;
    delete this.options;
    proxyquire.preserveCache();
    callback();
  },

  'test1': function ( t ) {
    t.expect( 2 );
    t.ok( ( this.app.result !== undefined ), 'async_function produced a result' );
    t.equal( this.app.result, 'zxcvbnm1234567890', 'result has value specified in the test' );
    t.done();
  },

  'test2': function ( t ) {
    t.expect( 2 );
    t.ok( ( this.app.result !== undefined ), 'async_function produced a result' );
    t.equal( this.app.result, 'zxcvbnm1234567890', 'result has value specified in the test' );
    t.done();
  }
});
```

Comment: I found the answer to this, simplified example and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328902/nodeunit-testing-event-based-async-code